# Vaadin ComboBox and vertical scrollbar

Tags: combobox, vaadin

I have following problem. Whenever i click on ComboBox the vertical scroll goes to the top of the window. This only happens if the subwindow is too big to fit in browser window. I'm trying to find solution for this over last four days with no result. Please someone help! :)

If anyone can look here is the video which better describes my problem:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2gfY_D9H8Y

Comment: @Johnny Graber Not much, really. I was tring setPositionTop() on my Panel with no result. I can't figured it out what causes this. There is no topic about this on Vaadin forum. Everything seems to be fine with my layout but it doesn't work as expected. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I have found the solution. Just added window.setWidth("someWidth") window.setHeight("someHeight") and it works. Previously I didn't have setHeight() to my window. Johnny, thanks again for replying!

Comment: You should Mark your question answered, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set height of a window:

window.setHeight("someHeight")

and it will work.